# Conversion issue Integer to int

Tags: java, collections

Unable to add the values in collections, when i`m trying to add the element getting below error message.

Error message that i`m getting "The method add(int, Integer) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (int)".

```
public static void additem(String type, List<Integer> list)
{
    long st=System.currentTimeMillis();

    for(int i=0;i<1E5;i++)
    {
    list.add(i);
    }
    long st1=System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Added Item is : " +list.get(0) + type+ "Time" +(st-st1));
}
```

Comment: I can't see any issue in this code.

Comment: Do you use Java >= 1.5 (when autoboxing was introduced) ?

Comment: @PeterMmm: There were no generic before 1.5, so he can't possibly be using a pre-1.5 compiler with this code.

Comment: @Peter and NPE I`m using java 1.8 version should not be any issue.

Answer (score 3):

`java.util.List` does have a [suitable `add()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-) and your code does [compile in Ideone](http://ideone.com/bnDLKD).

I therefore strongly suspect the `List` class in your example isn't `java.util.List` but is some other class.

Look at the `import` statements in your code to figure out what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Variable 'list' is a list of Integer 'List '. The argument of 'list.add' should not be 'int' but 'Integer'.

Your problem may solved by converting int to Integer in your code as follows.

```
public static void additem(String type, List<Integer> list)
{
    long st=System.currentTimeMillis();

    for(int i=0;i<1E5;i++)
    {
        list.add(new Integer(i)); // create Integer for using as argument.
    }
    long st1=System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Added Item is : " +list.get(0).toString + type+ "Time" +(st-st1)); // convert Integer to string for print.
}
```

Comment: Yes it did worked declaring (java.util.List list) inside method as parameter. But still i`m not sure what was wrong if we import it.!

Comment: I can't find 'add(int, Integer)' in your code in your question. Could you show the code which makes error message " "The method add(int, Integer) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (int)"".  I answered the way to make your code work. "declaring (java.util.List list) " is another issue.  Please focus issue by issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will fix your problem.

```
        public static void additem(String type, java.util.List<Integer> list){
        ...
        }
```

I suspect you just use java.awt.List

Comment: Import could be problem if you already have import like
import java.awt.List;

p.s. Sorry I haven't enough reputation for comment others answers))